# Mocha Fails if I change describe text

Tags: javascript, browser, mocha.js, chai

I am writing some Mocha/Chai tests using the browser version of Mocha. Mocha is failing without any error being thrown in the console if I change any piece of the string argument of a nested describe. Here's the working code:

```js
const fetchTestHTML = (path) => {
  //fetchJSON is a function from my code. It fetch's a file and parses using the provided parseMethod ('text' in this case). I really need to rename this function since it no longer only fetches JSON files.
  return fetchJSON(path,{},'text').then(text => $(text));
}

let context;
before(async ()=>{
  context = await fetchTestHTML('tests/html/statblock.test.html');
});
describe('Testing extraction of child nodes',()=>{
  describe('Getting self',() => {
    it('Given a selector of `&`, it should return the passed JQuery Collection',()=>{
      //findMatchingNodes is the function I am testing.
      findMatchingNodes('&',context,context).should.deep.equal(context);
    });
  });
});
```

The above gives me a correct test run with pass/fail output (success in this case). But if I change anything about the text passed to either of the `describe()` calls, Mocha fails (the page is just empty). For instance, just capitalizing the `s` in `self`:

```js
const fetchTestHTML = (path) => {
  //fetchJSON is a function from my code. It fetch's a file and parses using the provided parseMethod ('text' in this case). I really need to rename this function since it no longer only fetches JSON files.
  return fetchJSON(path,{},'text').then(text => $(text));
}

let context;
before(async ()=>{
  context = await fetchTestHTML('tests/html/statblock.test.html');
});
describe('Testing extraction of child nodes',()=>{
  describe('Getting Self',() => {
    it('Given a selector of `&`, it should return the passed JQuery Collection',()=>{
      findMatchingNodes('&',context,context).should.deep.equal(context);
    });
  });
});
```

This results in the mocha test div not being populated at all. No tests are run as far as I can tell.

If I remove either describe call, the Mocha environment also fails:

```js
const fetchTestHTML = (path) => {
  //fetchJSON is a function from my code. It fetch's a file and parses using the provided parseMethod ('text' in this case). I really need to rename this function since it no longer only fetches JSON files.
  return fetchJSON(path,{},'text').then(text => $(text));
}

let context;
before(async ()=>{
  context = await fetchTestHTML('tests/html/statblock.test.html');
});
describe('Getting self',() => {
  it('Given a selector of `&`, it should return the passed JQuery Collection',()=>{
    findMatchingNodes('&',context,context).should.deep.equal(context);
  });
});
```

And, if I add any additional describes with differing text within the first describe; the Mocha environment runs, but does not run the additional test(s):

```js
const fetchTestHTML = (path) => {
  return fetchJSON(path,{},'text').then(text => $(text));
}

let context;
before(async ()=>{
  context = await fetchTestHTML('tests/html/statblock.test.html');
});
describe('Testing extraction of child nodes',()=>{
  describe('Testing findNextNode',()=>{
    it('Should return the adjacent element',()=>{
      findNextNode($('#_idIndexMarker021'),context).should.deep.equal($('#_idTextAnchor003',context));
    });
  });
  describe('Getting self',() => {
    it('Given a selector of `&`, it should return the passed JQuery Collection',()=>{
      findMatchingNodes('&',context,context).should.deep.equal(context);
    });
  });
});
```

Results in the test inside `Getting self` running, but not the test(s) inside `Testing findNextNode`. If I change the describe text of the additional describe block to be `Getting self`, it runs correctly (in this case the test fails):

```js
const fetchTestHTML = (path) => {
  return fetchJSON(path,{},'text').then(text => $(text));
}

let context;
before(async ()=>{
  context = await fetchTestHTML('tests/html/statblock.test.html');
});
describe('Testing extraction of child nodes',()=>{
  describe('Getting self',()=>{
    it('Should return the adjacent element',()=>{
      findNextNode($('#_idIndexMarker021'),context).should.deep.equal($('#_idTextAnchor003',context));
    });
  });
  describe('Getting self',() => {
    it('Given a selector of `&`, it should return the passed JQuery Collection',()=>{
      findMatchingNodes('&',context,context).should.deep.equal(context);
    });
  });
});
```

I've got additional bizarre test cases, but this post is getting a little long in the tooth. Suffice it to say that if I do anything other than have my describes in the format (with these exact strings):

```js
describe('Testing extraction of child nodes',()=>{
  describe('Getting self',() => {
    //Test(s) for `Getting self`
  });
});
```

Then some or all of the tests fail to run. Anyone have a clue what's going on here? I've used Mocha for TDD on another project and never had anything remotely like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  My solution was to restart the browser and do an iisreset on my Windows server.  That seems to clear it up.

Not a great solution, so I hope I find something else!

Comment: Yep, no clue what caused it, but it resolved itself about 2 days later for me. Really wish I knew what caused this.